# AutoMapper - Interfaces as source

Tags: c#, automapper

My program in .NET Framework used `AutoMapper 2.0` and it create a map in this way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IChannel, Channel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsAlarm, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsAlarm))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveAlarms, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Alarms.Active))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status.ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsWarning, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsWarning))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveWarnings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Warnings.Active))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Measure));
```

Now I'm trying to move this program to .NET Core and I have to use the new versions of AutoMapper. I've tryied this way:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<IChannel, Channel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsAlarm, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsAlarm))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveAlarms, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Alarms.Active))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status.ToString()))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsWarning, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsWarning))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveWarnings, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Warnings.Active))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Measure));
});


var source = new IChannel(); //??

Mapper.Map<IChannel, Channel>(source);
```

Obviously I can't create an instance of an Interface. How can I replicate the first block of code with the newest versions of AutoMapper?

Comment: How did you create the IChannel instance before?

Comment: It's a public Interface with lot of datas settled in a different project than Channel. I used AutoMapper for extrapolate only datas that I need.

Comment: Well, thats nice but not asked. How did you get an instance of IChannel with .net Framework? Like *IChannel source = magic_powder_simsalabim*, or what?

Comment: With the old libraries `Mapper.CreateMap` you don't need to initialize anything. The code is all I published.